# Creating a script to open a webpage in a browser, login to the page and then auto refresh it every X amount of seconds

Tags: google-chrome, curl

I'm trying to create a script to automatically open chrome and login to my webpage, then auto refresh it every 30 seconds say.

I've tried to use curl as on this page: [How to login to website and auto-refresh page every X seconds from terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1433412/how-to-login-to-website-and-auto-refresh-page-every-x-seconds-from-terminal) to no avail.

Would appreciate any help possible

Answer (score 0):

You could open the URL with a script like this:

```
google-chrome https://example.com &
```

To execute the login, you could use `xdotool`, but the usage depends on the page itself. For example you could send multiple <kbd>TAB</kbd> until the the username gets its focus:

```
wid="$(xdotool getactivewindow | head -n 1)"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" key --delay 50 "Tab"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" key --delay 50 "Tab"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" type --delay 50 "username"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" key --delay 50 "Tab"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" type --delay 50 "password"
xdotool windowactivate "$wid" key--delay 50 "Enter"
```

Alternatively it would be possible to [move the mouse cursor and click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953486/xdotool-script-to-perform-mouse-moves-and-clicks), too.

And finally you could send <kbd>F5</kbd> in a while loop to reload the page every 30 seconds:

```
while true; do
  xdotool windowactivate "$wid" key --delay 50 "F5"
  sleep 30;
done
```